# g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--32’; did you mean ‘-m32’?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, g++

error code
This is my error code it says **--32** is the error line please help me solve the error

```
pravin@pravin-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/my os 2$ make loader.o
g++ --32 -o s@ loader.s
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--32’; did you mean ‘-m32’?
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'loader.o' failed
make: *** [loader.o] Error 1
```

I have tried to solve this problem but I can't so please help as soon as possible

makefile code

```
GCCPARAMS = -m32 -Iinclude -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -Wno-write-strings
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386
objects = loader.o kernel.o
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o s@ -c $<
%.o: %.s
    g++ $(ASPARAMS) -o s@ $<
mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)
install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

loader.s

```
.set MAGIC, 0x1badb002
.set FLAGS, (1<<0 | 1<<1)
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)
.section .multiboot
    .long MAGIC
    .long FLAGS
    .long CHECKSUM    
.section .text
.extern kernelMain
.extern callConstructors
.global loader
loader:
    mov $kernel_stack, %esp
    call callConstructors
    push %eax
    push %ebx
    call kernelMain
_stop:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp _stop
.section .bss
.space 2*1024*1024; # 2 MiB
kernel_stack:
```

if anyone know how to solve this problem. I want to learn how to make the operating system from scratch but this error sucks me

Comment: Isn't the error message self-explanatory? You're using `g++` not `as` as the assembler, so your `ASPARAMS` should be understood by `g++`.

The syntax to pass flags directly to the assembler invoked by `gcc` or `g++` is `-Wa,option` or `-Xassembler option`. So you should change it to either:
`ASPARAMS = -m32` or
`ASPARAMS = -Wa,--32`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that when you tag your question you are attracting the attention of the experts (or just the interested) people on that particular tag. Using the wrong tag for a question is always counterproductive and your question is particularly exposed to downvotes

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ASPARAMS = --32
> ...
>
> %.o: %.s
>     g++ $(ASPARAMS) -o s@ $<
> ```
>
> This is my error code it says --32 is the error line ...

Use `-Wa,--32`. `-Wa` passes arguments to the assembler, similar to the way `-Wl` passes arguments to the linker. You need `-Wa` and `-Wl` when using the compiler to drive the assembler and linker. Maybe something like:

```
CXX = g++
ASPARAMS = -Wa,--32
...

%.o: %.s
    $(CXX) $(ASPARAMS) -o s@ $<
```

If you were calling the assembler and linker directly, then you would not use `-Wa` and `-Wl`. For example, your makefile recipe might look like:

```
AS = as
ASPARAMS = --32
...

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(ASPARAMS) -o s@ $<
```

---

`ASPARAMS` and `GPPPARAMS` are a bit unusual. Typically you use `ASFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. Also see [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) in the make manual and [Variables for Specifying Commands](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command-Variables.html) in the GNU Coding Standards.

Maybe something like:

```
CXX = g++
AS = as
LD = ld

CPPFLAGS = -Iinclude
CXXFLAGS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -Wno-write-strings
ASFLAGS = --32
LDFLAGS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o s@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o s@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```